# Alternative to Rufus for Windows Vista

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, uefi, bootable-media, rufus

Are there any alternative to Rufus which would work on Windows Vista? I need to make a Windows 8.1 bootable UEFI USB and a Windows 10 bootable UEFI USB.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have against Rufus?

Comment: Format as FAT32, copy ISO contents(!) over, the end...?

Comment: What is wrong with the Microsoft supplied too for creating Windows 8.1 media? https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows8ISO

Comment: [Ramhound] Nothing against Rufus. As written above, I have a Vista machine and Rufus will not run on a Vista machine ...

Comment: [Mokubai] There might be some issues running them on Vista as every ISO I burn using their tool (on my Vista machine) MAY be causing a problem (or many) when attempting to clean install Win 8.1. Or my Vista machine is the problem. I am trying other options.

Comment: @silver_arrow - You should have pointed that out in your question, but it doesn't change the fact, Rufus still supports Vista if you use a previous version which has no problems handling Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 ISOs

Comment: @Ramhound I did; should it have been more explicit?  « Are there any alternative to Rufus which would work on Windows Vista? ... »

Thanks!''

Comment: @silver_arrow Questions seeking product recommendations are out of scope here at SuperUser.  Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 both have a Media Creation Tool you can use.  Rufus is better though.

Comment: @silver_arrow to address someone use `@`, otherwise they won't be notified

Comment: Link to Windows 7 version of Microsoft tool referenced by Mokubai: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rufus developer here.

Yes, we have stopped supporting Vista and XP in 3.0 and newer versions. But that doesn't mean you cannot use the older 2.x versions, which are compatible with those platforms.

You can find all the versions of Rufus that were ever publicly released [here](https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/). Internally, the differences between 2.18 (the last version compatible with XP and Vista) and 3.1 (latest at the time of this post) are minimal, so you should be able to achieve what you want by using 2.18.